# Android: Hide Text of custom TextView

Tags: android, user-interface, view, textview

I have a textView and I don't want the text to be printed, I want to draw it myself and hide the printed text.
How to hide the printed text?

EDIT: To explain the question as it seems nobody got it.
A text of TextView will be auto-printed (as it's a textView) but the problem is I'm already drawing the text and I don't want 2 versions of the text to appear of course ( the version that I drew and the auto-printed version)
I want to hide the auto-printed version of the text, but keep the text that I drew.

> public class myTextView extends TextView {
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
>      //drawing my text here with the current text...      
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Don't add anything to the `TextView` until you are ready?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, if I added anything to it, it will be auto-printed (as it's a textView) but the problem is I'm already drawing the text and I don't want 2 versions of the text to appear of course.

Comment: Look into setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)?

Comment: read the above comment.

Comment: I think I still misunderstand the question. Can you clarify with some kind of an example or somehow make it more clear?

Comment: Seems to me like you should just make your own View and make it behave the way you want (i.e. draw text in whatever manner you like "manually" using a canvas or something) Instead of trying to start from TextView. But it would be easier to guide you if you can be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @codeMagic: read FoamyGuy comment.

Comment: @FoamyGuy: If I used View, then the text that I draw will not be visible to UiAutomator, and I want my text to appear to the uiautomator.

Comment: @Ahmad have you created a subclass of TextView and overridden its draw method? If so edit your question and post the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: @Foamy I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the **Visibility** of the TextView?

```
TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

TextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Or setting its text to "".

```
TextView.setText("");
TextView.setText("yourtext");
```

Furthermore, you can initialize your TextView like that:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("yourtext"); // this will not draw the textview yet, it will not be visible
```

**Upon adding the TextView to a Layout, it will invoke its onDraw() method:**

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTv);
ll.addView(tv); // now the textview that we initialized before will be "visible"
```

### **UPDATE:**

If you are using a custom TextView, try calling:

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); // or whatever color you want your textview to be cleared with
```

**To clear the canvas (inside your onDraw() method), and then print your text.**

You could clear the canvas by drawing the color of your background, and then draw your desired text.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Are you using a custom TextView?

Comment: Yes, I'm using custom textView.

Answer (score 0):

for the version of text you want to hide just set it to black

`tv.setText("");` or `TextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

and then re-set it `tv.setText("text");` or `TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: you didn't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [TransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod) of TextView.

Here you have an example
https://gist.github.com/RicardAparicio/bdd6cd30410f9431e1da238202a1dfa9

Change some parameters if needed.